# Django with Tornado

Tags: python, django, tornado

I see a lot of people using django with tornado using WSGIContainer.  Does this make any sense?  Tornado is supposed to be asynchronous, but Django is synchronous.  Aren't you just shooting yourself in the foot by doing that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I haven't seen big projects that use tornado in front of django. But technically, you can do `monkey.patch_all()` with `gevent`. And then tornado will make sense. It's really bad solution, but if all you need is async unstable django waiting for you with chainsaw at the corner to cut your legs off instead of shooting them - then that is yours.

Comment: I don't really understand what this means, but I regret that I can only upvote once for your final sentence.

Answer (score 0):

Django comes with a debug server, so i guess, using Tornado with Django, the Tornado here is the mix of Apache + mod_WSGI